# File download from FTP to php://output doesn't work

Tags: php, ftp, buffer

I have made a web site with PHP and I have to download a file from FTP server.

I don't want to save temporarily the file on the web server, so I save it in the PHP buffer. But when I download it, the buffer apparently is empty because the filename matches but the file is empty.

Here's my code

```
ob_start();
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $_REQUEST["path"]);
ftp_get($conn_id, "php://output", $_REQUEST["remoteFile"], FTP_BINARY);
$data = ob_get_contents();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $_REQUEST["remoteFile"]);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
echo $data;
ob_end_clean();
exit;
```

For example, when I try to download a txt file, previously rightly uploaded, the filename is ok but content is empty.

Comment: What does the `ftp_get` return? Does the `ftp_get` (or any other `ftp_` function) return issue any PHP warning/error? Can you download the file anyhow on the same machine (e.g. using command-line `ftp`)? Give us any information, that we can use to debug your problem. You didn't tell us anything, apart from *"it does not work"*. We need [mcve]. - Also, if you have problems, first try a simple download to a file, before you start to combine it with output buffering!

Comment: the ftp_get return true and the PHP doesn't return any warning or error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point you are calling the `echo $data;`, the output buffering is still on. So you write the data back (second time) to the output buffer. And then you clear it. So nothing is outputted.

Just revert the `echo $data;` and `ob_end_clean();` calls:

```
ob_end_clean();
echo $data;
```

---

Though a way easier is to do something like:

```
$data = file_get_contents("ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/path/file.dat");
header(...);
echo $data;
```

Assuming [ftp:// protocol wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) are enabled.

And you do not need any buffering. And you also won't have the file twice in the memory at any point.

---

For even better implementation with `Content-Length` header, see:
[Download file via PHP script from FTP server to browser with Content-Length header without storing the file on the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47240635/850848)