# How to display image from FTP server in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, codeigniter-3

how to display image from FTP server without download the image to the local server?
in codeigniter library there are `upload, download, list_files, mirror`

Comment: See [Download file via PHP script from FTP server to browser with Content-Length header without storing the file on the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47240635/850848).

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Yeaaaah, SOLVED, thanks for your help, I used your linked tutorial above, and I removed header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file_path)); so I can view in browser. Firstly I load file list from FTP then use that tutorial from you

Best Regard

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean with open from ftp? 
if you mean is displaying image from hosting to web page, maybe this will help you
`<img src="ftp://username:password@my_ftp_ip_address/Images/imagename.jpg"/>`

Comment: I've trie like this: <img src="ftp://username:password@my_ftp_ip_address/Images/imagename.jpg"/>

but it' not working

Comment: i edit my answer

Comment: yes, I've tried like that, but no display or blank

Comment: Modern browsers won't load images from `ftp://` - For example Chrome does not support this since version 59: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5709390967472128, Firefox since version 61: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404744 - Use the solution from the question I've linked in a comment to the question.

Comment: Yes, I've used that tutorial @Martin, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'img';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.