# How to delete file after access it with ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, ftp

i save my site file within a ftp server. In following codes users can access ftp files via ajax request.

#### HTML

```
<a onclick="attach('354.tif')"><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function attach(fileLink) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var ajaxResponse;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        ajaxResponse = this.responseText;
        var response = JSON.parse(ajaxResponse);
        if(response.location){
            window.location.href = response.location;
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ajax/ftp-download.php?q=" + fileLink, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

#### ftp-download.php

```
<?php
define('__ROOT__',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once __ROOT__.'/config/ftpconfig.php'; 
require_once __ROOT__.'/functions/file-process/tiff-to-pdf.php';    
$ftp_file = '/'.$_REQUEST["q"];
$ftp_file_ext = pathinfo($ftp_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port) or die(err_handler(ftp_connect_error)); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$downloaded_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/user-files/".mt_rand(1000, 999999).".".$ftp_file_ext;

// try to download $ftp_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $downloaded_file, $ftp_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    if (strcasecmp($ftp_file_ext,"tif") == 0 or strcasecmp($ftp_file_ext,"tiff") == 0) {
        $output_file = "/user-files/".convert_tif_to_pdf($downloaded_file);     
    } else {
        $output_file = "/user-files/".basename($downloaded_file).PHP_EOL;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['location'=>$output_file]);
} 
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

I want to know is this possible delete `$downloaded_file` and `$output_file` after user access the file?

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for you to save the file to a temporary physical file on your web server.

You can send it directly to the client.

See [Download file via PHP script from FTP server to browser with Content-Length header without storing the file on the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47240635/850848).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Martin, finally i solve my problem with your Help.
I want to share my code, maybe it will help others.

**With following codes you can download files from ftp server and convert non PDF file into PDF with PHP Imagick class and view file in browser windows**

#### HTML Element

```
<a onclick="attach('354.tif')"><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

#### New ftp-download.php File

```
<?php

    $ftp_file = "/".$_REQUEST["q"];
    $ftp_file_ext = pathinfo($ftp_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $pdfFile = get_ftpfile_blob($ftp_file);


    if (strcasecmp($ftp_file_ext, 'pdf') != 0) {
        $pdfFile = convert_tif_to_pdf($pdfFile);    
    }

function get_ftpfile_blob($file) {

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/ftpconfig.php'; // this file contain ftp configuration

        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port); 
        ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
        ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

        ob_start();
        $result = ftp_get($conn_id, "php://output", $file, FTP_BINARY);
        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        ftp_close($conn_id);

        if ($result) {
            return $data;
        } else {
            die('');
        }
}

function convert_tif_to_pdf($inputFile) {
    $document = new Imagick();
    $document->readImageBlob($inputFile);
    $document->setFormat("pdf");
    return $document->getImagesBlob();  
}

    echo base64_encode($pdfFile);
    die();
?>
```

#### New jquery

```
function attach(fileLink) {
    $.get("/ajax/ftp-download.php", 
        {
            q: fileLink
        } , 
        function(data){
            // Display the returned data in browser
            if (data == "") {
                var modalWindow = '<div id="saveMsg" class="modal">' +
                                  '<p>File Not Found!</p>' +
                                  '<a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>' +
                                  '</div>';
                $('body').append(modalWindow);
                $('#saveMsg').modal({fadeDuration: 100});
                return;
            }
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            window.open(link);
        }
    );
}
```