php ftp file download always 0 bytes size
Yes I have read all the other posts regarding or similar to this.
Whenever I click to download the file from the ftp server it downloads the file but the size is always 0 bytes. The file types can vary: .jpeg, .jpg, .pdf, .odt etc.
<?php
$conn_id = ftp_connect( "myftpserver.org" );

$login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id, "uname", "pword" ) ;

$size = ftp_size ( $conn_id, $_REQUEST['downloadDir']."/".$_REQUEST['file'] ) ;

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($_REQUEST['file']) . '";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($size));
readfile("ftp://myftpserver.org".$_REQUEST['downloadDir']."/".$_REQUEST['file']);
exit;
?>

Note: The header parts I got from another post on here, not my own. I substituted my directory and filename

At the very least, if you need credentials to retrieve an FTP file size, you need credentials to download the file too. And there are no credentials in the FTP URL in your readfile call. For a better code, that doesn't need two connections to the FTP server, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47240635/850848

$size is already an int, so obviously filesize($size) is wrong.

As Martin Prikryl pointed out, there were no login credentials in:
readfile("ftp://myftpserver.org".$_REQUEST['downloadDir']."/".$_REQUEST['file']);
I changed it to:
readfile('ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.urlencode($ftp_user_pass).'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$_REQUEST['downloadDir']."/".$_REQUEST['file']);
and now it is working perfectly. Thank you Martin

But that's still wrong solution, as I've commented – because you are wastefully connecting twice to the FTP server.

You are right @MartinPrikryl, I changed the line just so others could see what I did wrong with my code. I am not using it as such, I am using the code in the link you provided.
